# Copy data from one field to another field in a same Table(MS ACCESS 2013)

Tags: ms-access

I'm learning MS access. So, pls tell me step by step.

Imagine a form where it asks user to input TWO information. One is Present Address and another one is Permanent Address.

I want to know how can I copy PRESENT ADDRESS data to PERMANENT ADDRESS data. But I don't want it to copy immediately. If I click a certain Button and PERMANENT ADRESS is empty(null) then it copy the data.

I found a video on youtube but it showed how to copy one form to another… Want to do it in same form…

Pls reply… Thanks is advance…

Comment: What do you want to use? VBA, SQL (you should edit your answer and add the appropriate tags)? Where are the values stored? In a table, in a variable? What's your code so far? Wow, I now have a lot more questions than you. You probably should go back to your question and edit it so it contains all necessary information for us to help you. We need to see your code and where it fails to do what you want. And you should definetely read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the OnClick event of the button, that will be:

```
If IsNull(Me![Permanent Address].Value) Then
    Me![Permanent Address].Value = Me![Present Address].Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the only reason for "present address" to be different from "permanent address" is if it is actually a "temporary address".

I would approach this differently.  Instead of calling the non-permanent address the "present" address, call it the "temporary" address.  Also, add a boolean (yes/no) field named UseTemporaryAddress.  Then you can use a query to get the present address, instead of pulling the data directly out of the table:

PresentAddress: IIf([UseTemporaryAddress], [TemporaryAddressField], [PermanentAddressField])